# Maintain state object in reactive flow / are the method level objects thread safe when using project reactor Mono or flux

Tags: java, project-reactor

I am developing a reactive flow sequence of calls to various API and want to maintain a state object. Is there a way to achieve it using https://projectreactor.io/ ? Below is what I did and what I want to accomplish

```
public Mono<MyDTO> test(AnotherDTO req) {
        MyDTO mDTO1 = new MyDTO(req); // ---> line_1
        // ... some code to update myDTO1 based on req object
        return api_1.get(mDTO1.getName()).flatMap(api_1_Res -> { // ---> 1
            mDTO1.setApi1Response(api_1_Res);
            return Mono.just(mDTO1);
        }).flatMap(monoResp -> {
            // ... some code to get a value from monoResp
            String var = monoResp.getApi1Response().getSomeValue();
            return api_2.get(var).flatMap(api_2_Res -> {
                monoResp.setApi2Response(api_2_Res);
                return Mono.just(monoResp);
            });
        }).flatMap(monoResp -> {
            // ... some code to get a value from monoResp
            String var1 = monoResp.getApi1Response().getSomeValue2();
            String var2 = monoResp.getApi2Response().getSomeInt();
            return api_3.get(var1, var2).flatMap(api_3_Res -> {
                monoResp.setApi3Response(api_3_Res);
                return Mono.just(monoResp);
            });
        }).flatMap(monoResp -> {
            saveIntoDB(monoResp);
        }).onErrorResume(errRes -> {
            log.error("exception {}", errRes.getMessage());
            return Mono.empty();
        });
    }
```

Questions:

1. How to maintain the state object so that if an error occurs at any of flatMap actions (1,2,3) the myDTO can contain the state till previous flatMap actions and get an access at onErrorResume?

Old question:
Can I use the above approach to maintain the state of myDTO
If an error occurs, how can I get the state of myDTO till the point where the error occurred? like if error occurs at api_2, get the myDTO till api_1 response so that I can save it in DB on error.

Comment: How you construct `mDTO2`, `mDTO3`, and `mDTO4`? Are they related in any way?

Comment: The DTO can be a simple object built using ‘new’ operator or using ‘lombok’ builders. I’m building them and returning so that the next flatMap can consume it. I’m lokkingIf there is a better way to share the object across multiple invocations which can also be shared for the error method that is what i’m looking @IgorArtamonov

Comment: I mean, is it different DTOs? Because guess by the variable names it's different types, and none of them is used after the modification. Like why you call `mDTO3.setApi3Response(api_3_Res)` if `mDTO3` instance is never used after that?

Comment: Is myDTO1 thread safe in reactor context? Based on what I understood it is not. So creating myDTO in each flatMap operations. @IgorArtamonov

Comment: Ah, so, it's the same DTO then? That was my question, if those DTOs are related or not. The code is incomplete and it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: In this particular case, for the code sample, it doesn't matter since it's a very simple logic. But in general you're right that it's safer to create a new copy with new values on the each step

Comment: @IgorArtamonov the question itself is how to maintain that state?

Comment: You can that as you said, using Lombok or `new`. If you make sure you have no shared state _between steps_ you're good.

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Updated question for more easy understanding

Answer (score 0):

When you need to pass a mutable state between steps it's better to create a new instance (i.e, have an immutable object) and return a new copy on each step. That ensures you don't get into a conflicting state when some of the steps repeated or executed in parallel. So you everything correctly by creating a new instance each time. In your case, though, it's not really necessary because you a simple step-by-step flow with simple Monos.

The second, regarding the error handling, is more complex. From my experience, with Reactor it's very easy to make a mistake and overlook some places to handle an error.

In general, I would suggest two approaches. First, you can always create own `Exception` class that would wrap your DTO and original exception:

```
class DtoException extends RuntimeException {
     final DTO dto;
     public DtoException(DTO dto, Throwable cause) {
         this.dto = dtop;
         super(cause);
     }
}

// and then

api.getSomething(dto.getField()).onErrorMap(t -> new DtoException(dto, t))
```

And then handle it somewhere downstream with `onErrorResume`.

Or you can write a function to save the state and use it directly:

```
Function<Mono<T>, Mono<T>> saveFailed(dto) {
   return { flow ->
      flow.onErrorResume( t -> { 
          dto.save();
          Mono.error(t)
      }
   }
}

// and then:

api.getSomething(dto.getField()).transform(saveFailed(dto))
```

The code above can be replaced with just `Function<Throwable, Mono<DTO>>` and passing it directly to `onErrorResume`, if that's more readable in your case.